# Solr use case insensitive field in managed schema

Tags: solr

I have a field use string type, i want it not tokenizer and case insensitive. I know use string field type and add a `LowerCaseFilterFactory` filter, but how could i do this in schemaless mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing different about doing it in the "schemaless" mode - you [use the Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html) to configure your Schema, or you *can* edit the managed schema manually if you only have one node.

But you can't attach a filter to a string field, so the field will have to be changed to a field type that has TextField as its base, then have it use `KeywordTokenizer` as its tokenizer and apply the filter to the result. The KeywordTokenizer keeps the input string as a single token, which is then lowercase by your filter - and the result is the same as what you'd get with a string field with an attached filter.

You can add a new field type through the Schema API by [invoking the `add-field-type` command on the schema endpoint](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-AddaNewFieldType):

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"myNewTxtField",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer":{
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" 
        }
        "filters":[{
           "class":"solr.LowercaseFilterFactory"
        }]
     }
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema
```